# input type="file" alternative in cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm developing a cordova android app but `input type="file"` doesn't work there.
Which alternative should I use to be able to see a prompt window before I load file?

Comment: Sounds like it's an HTML5 limitation on tablets, not just Cordova. Android and iOS don't support file browsing via HTML. You will need to use the [Cordova File](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File) plugin to natively access the device files.

Comment: @James Wong, is it possible to have prompt window and select a path to save or file to load using cordova file plugin?